# Process loses ability to see network drives (UnauthorizedAccessException) once every seven days. Found solution that works, but WHY does it work?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, kerberos

**SCENARIO**

Consider a small Windows domain consisting of a domain controller and five Windows 2016 member servers. On one of the member servers lives a .NET program I wrote which is responsible for starting and stopping other critical .NET processes.

When starting a process that lives on the same computer as the launcher, I use `Proces.Start()`, passing in the credentials to be used for the process via a `ProcessStartInfo` object.

But when starting a process on *remote* member server, I do something like this:

```
ConnectionOptions connOpts=new ConnectionOptions{
    Impersonation=ImpersonationLevel.Delegate,
    Authentication= AuthenticationLevel.Default,
    EnablePrivileges=false
};
if(usesCredentials){connOpts.Username=fqu.Username;connOpts.Password=password;}
new ManagementClass(
    new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2",machineName),connOpts),
    new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"),
    null
).InvokeMethod("Create",new String[]{Utils.DelimitItems(launchArgs,' ')});
```

When applying the second method to start a process on a remote machine, that process will properly launch and run. **But after exactly seven days, the process loses access to network shares on the domain, throwing `UnauthorizedAccessException` when any attempt to read or write files/directories is attempted**.

**SOLUTION**

I've been debugging this one for a very long time but I eventually discovered the solution:

On the domain controller, I navigate to:

Group Policy Management > Default Domain Policy > [edit] > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Account Policies > Kerberos Policy

Within that node is a key named "Maximum lifetime for ticket renewal" that is set to a default of seven days. Increasing this value to a higher number of days increases the length of time my processes can run without losing access to network shares.

**QUESTION**

What exactly is going on behind the scenes here? Presumably the remote server is successfully starting the process and telling it, "Ok, here's the domain account to use and here are the credentials. They're good for seven days." But why does this seven-day limitation exist, and why does it apply only when using the `ManagementClass`? If I tell a remote server to do something more traditional, like start a service for example, that service can run for far longer than seven days. Similarly, if `Process.Start()` is used to start a local process, it'll run for far longer than seven days. So what is it about this particular method of launching a process that triggers the seven day limitation on access to network shares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 7 day limitation is not for the credentials themselves, but for the derived TGT used for Kerberos authentication.

The way this works more or less is you send the creds to the remote machine and the remote machine uses those creds to request a TGT. That TGT is then used to request service tickets to your network shares.

A TGT lives for about 10 hours, with the ability to renew for up to 7 days (or as policy dictates). As long as you're within that window you can have all the access that account grants you. Once the 7 days are up you must reauthenticate using the creds to verify the account is still allowed to do things.

What appears to be happening is those creds are lost, probably explicitly removed as soon as they're used, so you can't ever get a new TGT. This is likely occurring because it's coming in as a network logon, and not an interactive logon. Services starting up save the creds locally so they can be queried as necessary and don't do network logon.

If you need to things to run for a very long time it's best to run a service directly on the machine.

Comment: I will probably migrate it to a service as you've suggested or, alternatively, create some simple launcher app on each member server that will start the processes via Process.Start(). It seems odd to me that launching via Process.Start() locally allows the process to properly cache its credentials and use them to re-create a ticket prior to renewal expiration, whereas ManagementClass forces this situation where the process immediately forgets its own credentials, leaving it powerless to create additional TGTs. I'll research network vs interactive logins to learn more.

Comment: It's not so much odd as it is intentional.